# How to extract the rttm format file from .wav audio file

Tags: python, ffmpeg, wav, sox

I would like to extract the .rttm file for an input .wav audio file in python

```
def extract_rttm_file(wav_path):
  """Extracts the .rttm file from the converted wav file.

  Args:
    wav_path: The path to the converted wav file.

  Returns:
    The path to the .rttm file.
  """

  output_path = os.path.splitext(wav_path)[0] + ".rttm"
  subprocess.call(["sox", wav_path, "-rttm", output_path])
  return output_path`
```

I tried the above code but it doesn't ouput the rttm file

Comment: Why do you believe `sox` can do that?  I don't see an `-rttm` option on the man page.  Converting speech to text is a very difficult operation and requires speech recognition software.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pyanote-audio](https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio) to do speaker diarization in python. See the [speaker-diarization](https://huggingface.co/pyannote/speaker-diarization) model on huggingface for more info.

Example:

```
# 1. visit hf.co/pyannote/speaker-diarization and accept user conditions
# 2. visit hf.co/pyannote/segmentation and accept user conditions
# 3. visit hf.co/settings/tokens to create an access token
# 4. instantiate pretrained speaker diarization pipeline
from pyannote.audio import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline.from_pretrained("pyannote/speaker-diarization@2.1",
                                    use_auth_token="ACCESS_TOKEN_GOES_HERE")


# apply the pipeline to an audio file
diarization = pipeline("audio.wav")

# dump the diarization output to disk using RTTM format
with open("audio.rttm", "w") as rttm:
    diarization.write_rttm(rttm)
```